# layout_alignRight not working properly

Tags: android, right-align

Can any one help me to create Ui as mentioned below. I am facing one issue while creating below Ui. When text is small, icon from the right bottom is not getting displayed. Please help. 

Here is the code.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/attachmentViewFL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_bg_incoming"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/attachmentRL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/nonThumbnailRL"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/attachmentIV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/extension_type_unknown" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/progressBarRL"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/attachmentIV"
                    android:text="text test  okay"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey_font"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@id/attachmentRL"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/rowChatMessageTimeTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="oct 20, 10:25 AM"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_font_dark"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowChatMessageStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/attachmentRL"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/attachmentRL"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rowChatMessageTimeTV"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_read_msg" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

If text is small then `ic_read_msg` icon is not displaying. But if text is large enough then it displays properly as I expect it to be displayed.
I don't want to use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` as it always fetch view to the right and matches screen's width.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `android:layout_alignRight="@id/attachmentRL` from ImageView.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowChatMessageStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/attachmentRL"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/attachmentRL" // ---> Remove this line
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rowChatMessageTimeTV"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_read_msg" />
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for the reply. But after removing android:layout_alignRight , it will be not placed at right position if message is at maximum width.